# Python. email. Unknown encoding

Tags: python, email, encoding, decoding

I'm trying to get content of emails from this file - *20030228_spam.tar.bz2* The dataset is so called Apache SpamAssassin’s public
datasets https://spamassassin.apache.org/old/publiccorpus/

I use the tarfile to get spam files

```
import tarfile
from email.parser import BytesParser, Parser
from email.policy import default
from pathlib import Path

DATA_DIR = Path('./data')
FILE_SPAM = Path(DATA_DIR, '20030228_spam.tar.bz2')

spam_mails = []

for file_, list_ in [(FILE_SPAM, spam_mails)]:
    with tarfile.open(file_) as tar_file:
        for item in tar_file.getmembers()[:]:
            if item.isfile():
                mail_bytes = tar_file.extractfile(item).read()
                mail = BytesParser(policy=default).parsebytes(mail_bytes)
                list_.append(mail)
```

I have a problem with a getting content of some emails.

```
list_exeption_index = []

for i, mail in enumerate(spam_mails):
    if not mail.is_multipart():
        try:
            mail.get_content()
        except Exception as ex:
            list_exeption_index.append(i)
list_exeption_index

output:
[217, 319, 388, 467]
```

There are 4 emails with some problems

```
for i in list_exeption_index:
    mail = spam_mails[i]
    try:
        mail.get_content()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

output:
    unknown encoding: DEFAULT_CHARSET
    unknown encoding: unknown-8bit
    unknown encoding: DEFAULT
    'multipart/alternative'
```

What is the problem and how can I overcome it?

Comment: Check such mails. And do not expect all mails are correct. As you see, it seems that some spammer (or list) is not set up properly and still have boiler template variables. You may need to define a fall-back encoding.

Comment: Ok, how can I set the ecoding for eamil if I define it?